# Ionic Framework: 1px vertical scroll even content with only 1 line of text

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

Does anyone have the same problem? My page content is not full. Just one line of text. But there is 1px vertical scroll. This happen to content in side menu too. Tried to search ionic forum and google, didn't have any info about this.

Is there a fix for this?

Comment: try setting height of body to 100vh

Comment: can you post some code please?

Comment: Related issue on Ionic GitHub : https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/2910

Comment: Did you solve this finally? I'm still running into this.

Comment: Hi, I give up Ionic already..

Answer (score 1):

Ionic scroll views "bounce" on iOS even if the scroll content isn't high enough to scroll to mimick the native behavior. To disable this, set `has-bouncing="false"` on the `<ion-content>`: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionContent/

Comment: Tried. Remain the same. Test on android and iOS

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried googling disable vertical scroll?
I get tons of results.

overflow-y: hidden; // hide vertical

overflow-x: hidden; // hide horizontal

Comment: Sometimes list have 1 item, sometimes will have more than screen can fit. Why would I think to disable vertical scroll?